# Math.ceil to nearest five at position 1

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, numbers

Okay....

I have a lot of uncontrolled numbers i want to round:

```
51255 -> 55000
25 -> 25
9214 -> 9500
13135 -> 15000
25123 -> 30000
```

I have tried modifying the numbers as string and counting length....

But is there a simple way using some Math function maybe?

Comment: If this was really a ceiling operation to the "nearest five at position 1" then wouldn't you want 25 to go to (stay at) 25? 24 to 25 yes, 26 to 30, yes, but it seems to me 25 to 25 is correct.

Comment: Yup, I'm lost too. Can you describe your desired rounding pattern?

Comment: So you effectively want something like 1.3 significant digits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my late answer. Uses no `Math` methods.

```
function toN5( x ) {
    var i = 5;
    while( x >= 100 ) {x/=10; i*=10;}
    return ((~~(x/5))+(x%5?1:0)) * i;
}
```

---

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/ujamoj/edit#javascript,live

```
   [51255, 24, 25, 26, 9214, 13135, 25123, 1, 9, 0].map( toN5 );

// [55000, 25, 25, 30, 9500, 15000, 30000, 5, 10, 0]
```

---

Or this is perhaps a bit cleaner:

```
function toN5( x ) {
    var i = 1;
    while( x >= 100 ) {x/=10; i*=10;}
    return (x + (5-((x%5)||5))) * i;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/idowan/edit#javascript,live

To break it down:

```
function toN5( x ) {
   //       v---we're going to reduce x to the tens place, and for each place
   //       v       reduction, we'll multiply i * 10 to restore x later.
    var i = 1;

   // as long as x >= 100, divide x by 10, and multiply i by 10.
    while( x >= 100 ) {x/=10; i*=10;}

   // Now round up to the next 5 by adding to x the difference between 5 and
   //    the remainder of x/5 (or if the remainder was 0, we substitute 5
   //    for the remainder, so it is (x + (5 - 5)), which of course equals x).

   // So then since we are now in either the tens or ones place, and we've
   //    rounded to the next 5 (or stayed the same), we multiply by i to restore
   //    x to its original place.
    return (x + (5-((x%5)||5))) * i;
}
```

---

Or to avoid logical operators, and just use arithmetic operators, we could do:

```
return (x + ((5-(x%5))%5)) * i;
```

And to spread it out a bit:

```
function toN5( x ) {
    var i = 1;
    while( x >= 100 ) {
        x/=10; 
        i*=10;
    }
    var remainder = x % 5;
    var distance_to_5 = (5 - remainder) % 5;
    return (x + distance_to_5) * i;
}
```

Comment: @Xeon06: Pretty, ain't she? ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
var numbers = [51255, 25, 9214, 13135, 25123, 3, 6];

function weird_round(a) {
    var len = a.toString().length;
    var div = len == 1 ? 1 : Math.pow(10, len - 2);
    return Math.ceil(a / 5 / div) * div * 5;
}

alert(numbers.map(weird_round));
```

Also updated for numbers below 10. Won't work properly for negative numbers either, just mention if you need this.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xeon06/8AHHE/1/)

Comment: I think that 25 is correct -- round to the nearest 5. It's 9214 that is incorrect (should be rounded to the nearest 500, which would be 9000, not 9500).

Comment: He mentionned ceiling in the question title.

Comment: +1 for using `toString().length` as a simpler way of determining magnitude than the log10 solutions @mblase75 and I did.

Answer (score 2):

```
    with(Math) {
        var exp = floor(log(number)/log(10)) - 1;
        exp = max(exp,0);
        var n = number/pow(10,exp);
        var n2 = ceil(n/5) * 5;
        var result = n2 * pow(10,exp);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NvvGf/4/

Caveat: only works for the natural numbers.

Comment: Updated -- my original solution broke for numbers less than 10.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why, but I thought it would be fun with regular expressions:

```
    var result = +(number.toString().replace(/([1-9])([0-9])(.+)/, function() {
        return Math.ceil(+(arguments[1] + '.' + arguments[2])) * 10 - (+arguments[2] < 5?5:0) + arguments[3].replace(/./g, '0');
    }));
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NvvGf/2/)

Comment: You and I don't have the same definition of fun mate :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function round(number) {
   var numberStr = number + "",
       max,
       i;

   if (numberStr[1] > '4') {
       numberStr[0] = parseInt(numberStr[0]) + 1;
       numberStr[1] = '0';
   } else {
       numberStr[1] = '5';
   }

   for (i = 2; max = numberStr.length; i < max; i += 1) {
      numberStr += '0';
   }

   return parseInt(numberStr);
}
```

Comment: @Phrogz: What exactly elegance is? Put all the code of a `function` on one single line, query every time the `length` property of an object or use `++i` in a for loop?

Comment: In my personal opinion performing math by turning numbers into strings is 'inelegant'.

Comment: @Phrogoz: Ok. But downvote is not for what you like or dislike.

Comment: I disagree (of course, since I did it). At the extreme (which this answer is not), an answer that 'works' but uses poor or unsafe coding practices should be downvoted in favor of answers that are better, in my opinion. Using strings unnecessarily for mathematics is sufficiently bad that I downvote. But don't worry, you got a sympathy upvote out of it, so a net +8 to your rep :p

Answer (score 0):

Strange coincidence, I wrote something really similar not so long ago!

```
function iSuckAtNames(n) {
    var n = n.toString(), len = n.length, res;

    //Check the second number. if it's less than a 5, round down,
    //If it's more/equal, round up

    //Either way, we'll need to use this:
    var res = parseFloat(n[0]) * Math.pow(10, len - 1); //e.g. 5 * 10^4 = 50000
    if (n[1] <= 5) {
        //we need to add a 5 right before the end!
        res += 5 * Math.pow(10, len - 2);
    }
    else {
        //We need another number of that size
        res += Math.pow(10, len - 1);
    }
    return res;
}
```